# I want to show only the first candle label as soon the condition satifies

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iama.png)

As shown in the image you can see 6 buy signals when the candle high crosses the green ( target line /entry).
I only need the one buy signal when the first candle crosses the entry line. but as you can see I am getting 6.

This is my code

```
//VWAP ploting
vwapSource = close
vwap = ta.vwap(vwapSource)
plot(vwap, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="VWAP")

//date and time input
inputTime =  input.time(timestamp("026 Jul 2023 09:45:00 GMT+5:30"), "Date")

//Searching Bar by time
searchBarTime = timestamp(year(time), month(time), dayofmonth(time), hour(inputTime), minute(inputTime))

// Check if the current bar matches the desired time
isTargetBar = time == searchBarTime

//ploting RSI and avg RSI
len = input(title="RSI Length", defval=14)
src = input(title="RSI Source", defval=close)
buffer = input(0.001, title="Buffer Length")
 
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
 
osc = ta.rsi(src, len)
rsiMA = ma(osc, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)

// plot(osc, title="RSI", linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 20))
// plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)

bufferHigh = high + (high * buffer)
bufferLow = low - (low * buffer)

bool isVwapAboveCandle = na
bool isVwapBelowCandle = na
bool isRsiAboveAvg = na
bool isRsipBelowAvg = na

if isTargetBar
    isVwapAboveCandle := vwap > close
    isVwapBelowCandle := vwap < close
    isRsiAboveAvg := osc > rsiMA
    isRsipBelowAvg := osc < rsiMA

buySignal = isVwapBelowCandle and isRsiAboveAvg
shortSignal = isVwapAboveCandle and isRsipBelowAvg


if buySignal
    buySignalTriangleUp = label.new(bar_index,(low-(0.004 * low)), style=label.style_triangleup, color=color.lime)

if shortSignal
    shortSignalTriangleDown = label.new(bar_index,(high+(0.004 * high)), style=label.style_triangledown, color=color.red)

// plotshape(buySignal, location = location.belowbar, style = shape.arrowup,  color = color.green, text ="BUY")
// plotshape(shortSignal, location = location.abovebar, style = shape.arrowdown,  color = color.red, text ="SHORT")

// //=====stoploss=====
var float sl = 0.0
for i = 1 to 5
    if buySignal or shortSignal //or shortcondition or pe_signalcondition1[i] or pe_signalcondition2[i])
        sl := bufferHigh - bufferLow
// //=========define target for long trades =======
tp1 = sl
tp2 = sl*2
tp3 = sl*3

if buySignal
    l1 = line.new ( bar_index, bufferHigh , bar_index + 7, bufferHigh, color = color.green, width = 2)
    l2 = line.new ( bar_index, bufferLow , bar_index + 7 , bufferLow , color = color.red , width = 2)
    l3 = line.new (bar_index, bufferHigh + tp1 , bar_index + 10 , bufferHigh+tp1, style=line.style_dotted, color=color.green, width = 1)
    l4 = line.new (bar_index, bufferHigh + tp2 , bar_index + 10 , bufferHigh+tp2, style=line.style_dotted, color=color.green, width = 1)
    l5 = line.new (bar_index, bufferHigh + tp3 , bar_index + 10 , bufferHigh+tp3, style=line.style_dotted, color=color.green, width = 1)
    
if shortSignal
    s1 = line.new ( bar_index, bufferLow , bar_index + 7, bufferLow, color = color.green, width = 2)
    s2 = line.new ( bar_index, bufferHigh , bar_index + 7, bufferHigh, color = color.red, width = 2)
    s3 = line.new ( bar_index, bufferLow - tp1, bar_index + 10, bufferLow - tp1, color = color.green,style=line.style_dotted, width = 1)
    s4 = line.new ( bar_index, bufferLow - tp2, bar_index + 10, bufferLow - tp2, color = color.green,style=line.style_dotted, width = 1)
    s5 = line.new ( bar_index, bufferLow - tp3, bar_index + 10, bufferLow - tp3, color = color.green,style=line.style_dotted, width = 1)

buyLine = buySignal ? bufferHigh : na
StopLossforBuy = buySignal ? bufferLow : na
shortLine = shortSignal ? bufferLow : na
StopLossforSell = shortSignal ? bufferHigh : na

longCondition = high >= buyLine[1] or high >= buyLine[2] or high >= buyLine[3] or high >= buyLine[4] or high >= buyLine[5] or high >= buyLine[6]
longPositionNegated = low <= StopLossforBuy[1] or low <= StopLossforBuy[2] or low <= StopLossforBuy[3] or low <= StopLossforBuy[4] or low <= StopLossforBuy[5] or  low <= StopLossforBuy[6] 
shortCondition = low <= shortLine[1] or low <= shortLine[2] or low <= shortLine[3] or low <= shortLine[4] or low <= shortLine[5] or  low <= shortLine[6] 
shortPositionNegated = high >= StopLossforSell[1] or high >= StopLossforSell[2] or high >= StopLossforSell[3] or high >= StopLossforSell[4] or high >= StopLossforSell[5] or  high >= StopLossforSell[6] 

if longPositionNegated
    pnL = label.new(bar_index,(low- (0.004 * low)), style=label.style_arrowup, color=color.white, text="pNeg", textcolor=color.white)
    label.delete(pnL)

else if shortPositionNegated
    pnS = label.new(bar_index,(high+ (0.002 * high)), style=label.style_arrowdown, color=color.white, text="pNeg", textcolor=color.white)
    
else if longCondition
    p1 = label.new(bar_index,(low- (0.004 * low)), style=label.style_arrowup, color=color.white, text="BUY", textcolor=color.white)

else if shortCondition
    p2 = label.new(bar_index,(high+ (0.002 * high)), style=label.style_arrowdown, color=color.white, text="SELL", textcolor=color.white)
```

I tried storing the bar index and all but I was not getting a proper way to do it. I am new to Pine script

Answer (score 0):

You have a condition like `high >= buyLine[1]`. This will be `true` as long as the `high` price is above your `buyLine[1]`. That's why you are getting multiple labels.

Instead of doing that, you can use the `ta.crossover()` function which will return `true` only on the bar that price crosses over your line. And for shorts, you can use `ta.crossunder()`.

Comment: `longCondition = ta.crossover(high, buyLine[1] ) or ta.crossover(high, buyLine[2] ) or ta.crossover(high, buyLine[2]) or ta.crossover(high, buyLine[3]) or  ta.crossover(high, buyLine[4]) or  ta.crossover(high, buyLine[5]) or  ta.crossover(high, buyLine[6])`

i modified my code to this , but did not work